# angular.extend has 2 args or 3 args

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In the [angularjs documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.extend), it said that `angular.extend` extends the destination object dst by copying own enumerable properties from the `src` object(s) to `dst`. If you want to preserve original objects, you can do so by passing an empty object as the target: `var object = angular.extend({}, object1, object2)`.

I am quite confused with the number of `args` in the statement above. Because the usage of `angular.extend` should be 2 `args` :

```
angular.extend(dst, src);
```

Thus, `angular.extend` has 2 `args` or 3 `args` on earth?

Comment: Both. It probably checks if `arguments[2]` is populated and acts accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It 'has both' 2 and 3 args.

Taken from the source:

```
 * @param {Object} dst Destination object.
 * @param {...Object} src Source object(s).
 * @returns {Object} Reference to `dst`.
 */
function extend(dst) {
  return baseExtend(dst, slice.call(arguments, 1), false);
}
```

Angular takes the `arguments` from index `1` and extends them onto the destination of parameter `dst`.

The JSDoc explains that you can have multiple source objects that will go into the destination. You could even have 4, 5, or more arguments provided.